# PY3 import dict from .py file, how do I update the dict if key does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, module

```
def Update_Dict(TID):
    print ("need IP for %s" %(TID) )
    IP = input ("IP - ")
    Hosts.NE_IP.append["%s"%(TID) , "%s" %(IP)]
    
    return TID, IP

with open(file,"r") as fh:
    for lines in fh:
        if not lines.strip():
                continue
        else:
            EXP_Rate, param = lines.strip().split("/")
            TID, SH_SL_PT = param.split(",")

            if TID in NE_IP:
                IP = Hosts.NE_IP["%s" %(TID)]
                pass
            else:
                TID, IP = Update_Dict(TID)

            UID = Hosts.CREDS["UID"]
            PWD = Hosts.CREDS["PWD"]
   
            with open("%s\Report.txt" %(Dir_Path), "a") as fReport:
                fReport.write("%s-%s\n" %(TID, IP) )
                fReport.write("%s-%s\n\n" %(UID, PWD) )
```

What this is doing is, I have a list of Hosts that I am wanting to login to and run commands on.
Initially I had the text pad input file as rate/UID, PWD, HostName, IP, SH-SL-PT and wanting to change it to rate/HostName, SH-SL-PT    since the UID and PWD are all the same and instead of always inputting the IP's every time, want to put the HostName and the IP in a dict. The way it is now, it does ask for the IP if the key is not present and prints out the way it should.

How do I update the .py file dict with the new key:value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, your code snippet is not very clear and reproducible, but as for

> update the dict if key does not exist

the answer would be using [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples).

You'd set the default value, like `None` or empty string or whatever object factory and then modify/access the object whether the key was or wasn't set before.

Comment: Decided to go with JSON instead of a .py file to hold the dict..